# How do I create rows in increments of 10 minutes between two timestamps, such that the end time of one row equals the start time of the next row?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-analysis

I have a dataset that has four columns, two of which are time stamps - "Start_time" and "End_time". The "Time_diff" column is the difference between start time and end time. The "Bus" column is the count of buses recorded within the timeframe.

Each time difference should be less than or equal to 10. However I have entries where the time differences are greater than 10, as illustrated below (row 3).

| Start_time | End_time | Time_diff | Bus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-13 11:20:00.00 | 2023-12-13 11:30:00 | 10 | 10 |
| 2023-12-13 11:36:00.00 | 2023-12-13 11:40:00 | 4 | 3 |
| 2023-12-13 11:40:00.00 | 2023-12-13 12:10:00 | 30 | 23 |
| 2023-12-13 13:00:00.00 | 2023-12-13 13:10:00 | 10 | 7 |
| 2023-12-13 13:10:00.00 | 2023-12-13 13:20:00 | 10 | 9 |

I want to create additional rows in increments of 10 minutes breaking up the two timestamps with time differences greater than 10, such that the end time of one row equals the start time of the next row.

This is the function I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def generate_rows(df, start_col, end_col):
    # Set the time difference increment
    time_difference = pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)

    # Create additional rows
    new_rows = []
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        current_time = row[start_col]
        end_time = row[end_col]
        while current_time < end_time:
            new_end_time = current_time + time_difference
            new_row = {col: np.nan for col in df.columns}
            new_row[start_col] = current_time
            new_row[end_col] = new_end_time
            new_rows.append(new_row)
            current_time = new_end_time

    # Convert the list of dictionaries to a DataFrame
    new_rows_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)

    return pd.concat([df, new_rows_df]).sort_values(by=start_col).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This is what I expect as output:

| Start_time | End_time | Time_diff | Bus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-13 11:20:00.00 | 2023-12-13 11:30:00 | 10 | 10 |
| 2023-12-13 11:30:00.00 | 2023-12-13 11:36:00 | 6 | NaN |
| 2023-12-13 11:36:00.00 | 2023-12-13 11:40:00 | 4 | 3 |
| 2023-12-13 11:40:00.00 | 2023-12-13 11:50:00 | 10 | NaN |
| 2023-12-13 11:50:00.00 | 2023-12-13 12:00:00 | 10 | NaN |
| 2023-12-13 12:00:00.00 | 2023-12-13 12:10:00 | 10 | 23 |
| 2023-12-13 13:00:00.00 | 2023-12-13 13:10:00 | 10 | 7 |
| 2023-12-13 13:10:00.00 | 2023-12-13 13:20:00 | 10 | 9 |

Before running this function, I find that there are 19 rows in my dataset where time diff is greater than 10. After running the code there are still 19 rows with time diff greater than 10. Please help!!!

Comment: It looks like you are creating a dataframe of new_rows, and appending that to the original dataframe. Nowhere do I see you drop the rows with timedelta > 10 from the original dataframe.

Comment: Also, doesn't this make too many new rows? It seems like you are making new rows for ***every*** row in the original dataframe, not just those with timedelta > 10.

Comment: Lastly, I don't think you should always add 10 to create new_end_time, because there could be timedeltas greater than 10 that aren't multiples of 10. Wouldn't you want to split a row with timedelta 16 into two rows: one with timedelta 10 and the other with timedelta 6?

Comment: @Joe. You're absolutely right. That is exactly my goal. If you could just point out where I need to make the adjustments, I would be most grateful. I'm sort of newbie. Thank you

Comment: I would recommend not concatenating to the original df inside the function, just return the new_rows_df. Then feed your function the original dataframe filtered to only include the rows with timedelta > 10, and concatenate the df returned to the original df with only rows with timedelta < 10.

Comment: Also, make `new_end_time = min(current_time + time_difference, end_time)`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a loop for this, but rather vectorial operations.

You can [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the rows as many times as needed to split the value to a maximum of 10, then recompute the diff, the start and end:

```
MAX = 10

# ensure datetime64
df[['Start_time', 'End_time']] = df[['Start_time', 'End_time']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# identify rows to duplicate
d, r = df['Time_diff'].divmod(MAX)
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(d+r.ne(0)*2)]

# correct Time_diff
g = out.groupby(level=0)

out['Time_diff'] = (g['Time_diff'].transform('last')
                    .sub(g.cumcount(ascending=False)*MAX)
                    .clip(upper=MAX).abs()
                   )

# Only keep last "Bus" per original row
m = out.index.duplicated(keep='last')
out.loc[m, 'Bus'] = np.nan

# Decrement End_time from original end
end = g['End_time'].transform('last')
out['End_time'] = end.sub(pd.to_timedelta(out
                          .loc[::-1, 'Time_diff']
                          .groupby(level=0)
                          .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift())
                          [::-1], unit='min')
                         ).fillna(end)
# Update Start_time
out['Start_time'] = out['End_time'].sub(pd.to_timedelta(out['Time_diff'], unit='min'))
```

Output:

```
          Start_time            End_time  Time_diff   Bus
0 2023-12-13 11:20:00 2023-12-13 11:30:00         10  10.0
1 2023-12-13 11:30:00 2023-12-13 11:36:00          6   NaN
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00          4   3.0
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 11:50:00         10   NaN
2 2023-12-13 11:50:00 2023-12-13 12:00:00         10   NaN
2 2023-12-13 12:00:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         10  23.0
3 2023-12-13 13:00:00 2023-12-13 13:10:00         10   7.0
4 2023-12-13 13:10:00 2023-12-13 13:20:00         10   9.0
```

##### How it works

###### first identify the rows to duplicate

for that we use [`divmod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.divmod.html) to get the divider and remainder. This gives use the number of lines with the formula `number of rows = divider + (2 is remainder is not null)` (e.g. `30 -> 3 + 0`, `4 -> 0 + 2`, `29 -> 2 + 2`). We use that to duplicate the rows with [`index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html)

Now we have duplicated rows with exactly the same information:

```
d, r = df['Time_diff'].divmod(MAX)
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(d+r.ne(0)*2)]

           Start_time            End_time  Time_diff  Bus
0 2023-12-13 11:20:00 2023-12-13 11:30:00         10   10
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00          4    3
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00          4    3
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         30   23
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         30   23
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         30   23
3 2023-12-13 13:00:00 2023-12-13 13:10:00         10    7
4 2023-12-13 13:10:00 2023-12-13 13:20:00         10    9
```

###### correcting the Time_diff

For that we use a `groupby.cumcount` to enumerate the rows in each group (from the end) and we subtract 10 min for each row, then `clip` the value to 10 min:

```
           Start_time            End_time  Time_diff  Bus  cumcount  cumcount*MAX  clip(upper=MAX)  abs  Time_diff_corr
0 2023-12-13 11:20:00 2023-12-13 11:30:00         10   10         0             0               10   10              10
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00          6    3         1            10               -6    6               6
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00          4    3         0             0                4    4               4
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         10   23         2            20              -10   10              10
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00          0   23         1            10                0    0               0
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         10   23         0             0               10   10              10
3 2023-12-13 13:00:00 2023-12-13 13:10:00         10    7         0             0               10   10              10
4 2023-12-13 13:10:00 2023-12-13 13:20:00         10    9         0             0               10   10              10
```

###### hiding the Bus values

We use [`Index.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) to identify the last value per index and mask the other ones:

```
m = out.index.duplicated(keep='last')
out.loc[m, 'Bus'] = np.nan

           Start_time            End_time  Time_diff   Bus      m
0 2023-12-13 11:20:00 2023-12-13 11:30:00         10  10.0  False
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00          6   NaN   True
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00          4   3.0  False
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         10   NaN   True
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00          0   NaN   True
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         10  23.0  False
3 2023-12-13 13:00:00 2023-12-13 13:10:00         10   7.0  False
4 2023-12-13 13:10:00 2023-12-13 13:20:00         10   9.0  False
```

###### correcting the End

We compute a reversed, shifted `cumsum`, per group, convert to timedelta and subtract from the last time per group (obtained with [`groupby.transform('last')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)):

```
           Start_time            End_time  Time_diff   Bus  reverse_cumsum_shift    as_timedelta        sub_from_end       End_corrected
0 2023-12-13 11:20:00 2023-12-13 11:30:00         10  10.0                   NaN             NaT                 NaT 2023-12-13 11:30:00
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00          6   NaN                   4.0 0 days 00:04:00 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:36:00
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00          4   3.0                   NaN             NaT                 NaT 2023-12-13 11:40:00
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         10   NaN                  10.0 0 days 00:10:00 2023-12-13 12:00:00 2023-12-13 12:00:00
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00          0   NaN                  10.0 0 days 00:10:00 2023-12-13 12:00:00 2023-12-13 12:00:00
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         10  23.0                   NaN             NaT                 NaT 2023-12-13 12:10:00
3 2023-12-13 13:00:00 2023-12-13 13:10:00         10   7.0                   NaN             NaT                 NaT 2023-12-13 13:10:00
4 2023-12-13 13:10:00 2023-12-13 13:20:00         10   9.0                   NaN             NaT                 NaT 2023-12-13 13:20:00
```

###### correcting the start

Now that we have a correct End, we subtract Time_diff * 10min to each End to get the Start:

```
out['Start_time'] = out['End_time'].sub(pd.to_timedelta(out['Time_diff'], unit='min'))

           Start_time            End_time  Time_diff   Bus
0 2023-12-13 11:20:00 2023-12-13 11:30:00         10  10.0
1 2023-12-13 11:30:00 2023-12-13 11:36:00          6   NaN
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00          4   3.0
2 2023-12-13 11:50:00 2023-12-13 12:00:00         10   NaN
2 2023-12-13 12:00:00 2023-12-13 12:00:00          0   NaN
2 2023-12-13 12:00:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00         10  23.0
3 2023-12-13 13:00:00 2023-12-13 13:10:00         10   7.0
4 2023-12-13 13:10:00 2023-12-13 13:20:00         10   9.0
```

Comment: too hard to understand

Comment: @ombk there are indeed many steps, but each step is not so complex. Which part is difficult for you to understand?

Comment: Everything, minus the line of divmod. If I read it line by line I can't imagine whats the result on each level unless I run it. It can be written more elegantly (imo).

I totally understand that the question is not easy also. 
Personally im not able to come up with an answer :) (in all honesty)

Comment: @ombk I added some more details and the intermediates, hopefully this is easier to understand (again, it's a lot of small steps).

Answer (score 0):

Another option. No need to create additional columns.

```
import pandas as pd

def split_time_intervals(df, start_col, end_col, max_diff=10):
    new_rows = []
    
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        start_time = row[start_col]
        end_time = row[end_col]
        bus_count = row['Bus']

        while (end_time - start_time).total_seconds() / 60 > max_diff:
            new_end_time = start_time + pd.Timedelta(minutes=max_diff)
            new_rows.append({start_col: start_time, end_col: new_end_time, 'Bus': None})
            start_time = new_end_time

        new_rows.append({start_col: start_time, end_col: end_time, 'Bus': bus_count})

    return pd.DataFrame(new_rows)

# Sample dataset
data = {
    'Start_time': pd.to_datetime(['2023-12-13 11:20', '2023-12-13 11:36', '2023-12-13 11:40', '2023-12-13 13:00', '2023-12-13 13:10']),
    'End_time': pd.to_datetime(['2023-12-13 11:30', '2023-12-13 11:40', '2023-12-13 12:10', '2023-12-13 13:10', '2023-12-13 13:20']),
    'Bus': [10, 3, 23, 7, 9]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Apply the function
new_df = split_time_intervals(df, 'Start_time', 'End_time')
print(new_df)



Start_time            End_time          Bus
0 2023-12-13 11:20:00 2023-12-13 11:30:00  10.0
1 2023-12-13 11:36:00 2023-12-13 11:40:00   3.0
2 2023-12-13 11:40:00 2023-12-13 11:50:00   NaN
3 2023-12-13 11:50:00 2023-12-13 12:00:00   NaN
4 2023-12-13 12:00:00 2023-12-13 12:10:00  23.0
5 2023-12-13 13:00:00 2023-12-13 13:10:00   7.0
6 2023-12-13 13:10:00 2023-12-13 13:20:00   9.0
```